# Using RequireJS to load D3 and Word Cloud Layout

Tags: d3.js, svg, requirejs

I am experiencing issues when trying to load D3 v4.8 and word cloud layout component (https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) using the RequireJS. While both D3.js and d3.layout.cloud.js are being downloaded to the browser, an exception is being thrown indicating the d3.layout.cloud is not a function.

Here is how I am configuring the RequireJS:

```
require.config({
    waitSeconds: 10,

    baseUrl: './scripts',

    paths: {
        d3: 'd3.min',
        jquery: 'jquery-2.1.0.min',
        cloud: 'd3.layout.cloud'
    },

    shim: {


    cloud: {
        deps:['jquery', 'd3']
    }

}

});
```

The line of code that throws an exception is d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height]) and can be found in the function below:

```
function wordCloud(selector) {

    var width = $(selector).width();
    var height = $(selector).height();

    //var fill = d3.scale.category20();

    //Construct the word cloud's SVG element
    var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+ width/2 +","+ height/2 +")")

    var fill = d3.scale.category20();

    //Draw the word cloud
    function draw(words) {
        var cloud = svg.selectAll("g text")
            .data(words, function(d) { return d.text; })

        //Entering words
        cloud.enter()
            .append("text")
            .style("font-family", "Impact")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr('font-size', 1)
            .style("cursor", "hand")
            .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
            .on("click", function (d, i){
                window.open("http://www.google.com/?q=" + d.text, "_blank");
            });

        //Entering and existing words
        cloud
            .transition()
            .duration(600)
            .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .style("fill-opacity", 1);

        //Exiting words
        cloud.exit()
            .transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
            .attr('font-size', 1)
            .remove();
    }


    //Use the module pattern to encapsulate the visualisation code. We'll
    // expose only the parts that need to be public.
    return {

        //Recompute the word cloud for a new set of words. This method will
        // asycnhronously call draw when the layout has been computed.
        //The outside world will need to call this function, so make it part
        // of the wordCloud return value.
        update: function(words) {

            // min/max word size
            var minSize = d3.min(words, function(d) { return d.size; });
            var maxSize = d3.max(words, function(d) { return d.size; });

            var textScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([minSize,maxSize])
                .range([15,30]);

            d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
                .words(words.map(function(d) {
                    return {text: d.text, size: textScale(d.size) };
                }))
                .padding(5)
                .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
                .font("Impact")
                .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
                .on("end", draw)
                .start();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado, I will try to run one of my examples with D3  v3.x very soon. I'll let you know how it goes... Thanks for the suggestion about the bounty too.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with d3-cloud's reliance on d3v4. Looking through the entire d3-cloud's source code [here](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/index.js) you can see that the only dependency is `d3-dispatch`, which I'd guess is loading just fine. I believe the issue is that you're trying to require it into `d3.layout.cloud`, because `d3.layout` is `undefined` in d3v4. Try just changing all references to `d3.layout.cloud` to `d3.cloud` (i.e. both in require's config and in your source code).

Comment: @UncleZen I deleted my comment, since d3-cloud works with D3 v4.x.

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of d3-cloud only depends on d3-dispatch so it should work fine with any version of D3.  I think the issue here is that you're using RequireJS ([AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)) to reference the `d3.layout.cloud.js` file, but you're not using RequireJS to **use** the library (configured as `cloud` in your example).  See the following [example](https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/6656b8ea2619cda2d290ef4ebd36f4e5/6758b702d158277722e46e48a69653d4fd7a5d73):

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: ".",
  paths: {
    cloud: "d3.layout.cloud" // refers to ./d3.layout.cloud.js
  }
});

requirejs(["cloud"], function(cloud) { // depends on "cloud" defined above
  cloud()
    .size([100, 100])
    .words([{text: "test"}])
    .on("word", function() {
      console.log("it worked!");
    })
    .start();
});
```

If you prefer to use CommonJS-style `require(…)` you can also use this with RequireJS if you use the appropriate `define(…)` syntax, like in this [quick example](https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/5d88eaa7bdc776fbae67f96718614eda).

Comment: But `var cloud = require("cloud");` is not AMD syntax, won't work with RequireJS, will it?

Comment: I simply adapted the first RequireJS example that I could find,
 which uses `require(…)` [here](https://github.com/volojs/create-template/blob/master/www/app/main.js#L9).

Comment: Ah, I see. This example is not suitable for a browser JS runtime, it's for node.

Comment: Node is simply used as a build tool. This is a canonical example for using RequireJS and using `require(…)` works fine in a browser environment (I just checked to be sure).

Comment: The resulting built file (that includes all dependencies) can use `var x = require('x')`, yes, but that syntax won't work here when RequireJS is used to download the dependencies from the browser, and I thought that was the case here (because I don't see a good reason to use RequireJS voluntarily for your own sources if you use node as a build tool)

Comment: No, you're wrong: RequireJS automatically handles it; see [my quick example](https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/5d88eaa7bdc776fbae67f96718614eda).

Comment: *But* I do take your (implied) point that it seems sensible to avoid using CommonJS in a canonical example (probably something to take up with the RequireJS authors). I will update my answer to reflect this now.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I was wrong. In the example you referenced initially, I saw mentions of `node tools/r.js -o tools/build.js` and I assumed the syntax was in the resulting build. But no, you're right, that syntax works, using the `require` object passed by requirejs as argument of callback passed to `define` (phew). I completely missed that.

Comment: Oh man, Jason Davies, I wish you had gotten at least some of the bounty for this.

Comment: @meetamit  I did not know how to share the bounty :(.

Answer (score 3):

While d3-cloud itself is compatible with both D3 V3 and V4, most examples you will find are not, and your current code is not, it can only work with V3.

To make it work with V4 you need to replace all references to `d3.scale`.
For example, `d3.scale.category20()` becomes `d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20)`.
For a small runnable example that is compatible with both, see [Fiddle #1](https://jsfiddle.net/ruaz7269/3/). It uses RequireJS to load d3, d3-cloud, and jQuery. Try changing the D3 version in require config at top of JS part.

Let's settle on V3 for now, since your code relies on it. There are still a few issues:

Your must use objects for d3 & d3cloud & jQuery that are obtained via a call to `require`. And with RequireJS this is asynchronous (because it needs to fetch the JS scripts programmatically, and in a browser that can only be done asynchronously). You put your code within a callback function (for more info, see RequireJS docs):

[ Edit: see Jason's answer for alternative syntax. ]

```
require(['d3', 'd3cloud', 'jQuery'], function(d3, d3cloud, $) {
    /* Your code here.
       Inside "require" function that you just called,
       RequireJS will fetch the 3 named dependencies,
       and at the end will invoke this callback function,
       passing the 3 dependencies as arguments in required order.
     */
});
```

In this context (and versions) d3 cloud main function is not available under `d3.layout.cloud()`, so you need to replace that with `d3cloud()`, assuming that's the name of the argument passed as callback to `require`.

You must make sure you *never* pass width or height of 0 to `d3cloud.size([width, height])`, or it will enter an infinite loop. Unfortunately it can easily happen if you use `$(selector).height()`, depending on content of your page, and possible "accidents". I suggest `var height = $(selector).height() || 10;` for example.

Not a programming problem, but the function you pass to `.rotate()` is taken from an example, and maybe you want to change that: it yields only 2 possible values, 0 or 90, I find this monotonous, the default one is prettier. So I removed the line entirely in the example below. Maybe you'll want it back, just add your `.rotate(...)` line.

[Fiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/06yqb3x4/): a complete working example based on your piece of code.